# Stuck with "Configurable" haskell class

Tags: haskell

I've been tinkering with little program and it's slowly driving me crazy. Consider the following program (https://repl.it/repls/ItchyShorttermEvents), the goal is to construct any data type by  prompting the user to fill each argument through te command line. I've been abstracting the implementation more and more.

The idea is based on a type class `Configurable`. Any data type in this class can be "configured" by running `configure :: IO (name of data type you want to configure)`. For instance running `configure::IO Int` prompts the user to enter an integer and that same integer is returned.

To avoid writing instances for lot's of different data types the goal now is to make it so that all data types that derive [`Data`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html) are `Configurable` (probably not very idiomatic but i think it's cool). For algebraic data type I can find all constructors (or more precisely [an abstract representations of the constructor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Constr)) associated with that data type. I am how ever not able to construct this constructor correctly.

I believe this should be done using [`gunfold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:gunfold). This unfold function constructs the constructor based on the abstract representation of the constructor. The signature for this function is: `gunfold :: (forall b r. Data b => c (b -> r) -> c r) -> (forall r. r -> c r) -> Constr -> c a`. The second argument of this function is used to apply the parameters to the constructor. My idea was to recursively apply the `configure` function to prompt the user for each parameter of the constructor. However due to the  `Data b =>` constraint I'm not able to use all Configurable instances (which is required for certain types).

If for instance I want to construct the data type `ABC` as described in the program. The `C` constructer can correctly be constructed as it does not require any parameters, the `B` constructer can correctly be constructed as it's only parameter is another algebraic data type which fulfills the `Data b =>` constraints. I'm however unable to construct the `A` constructor as it's paramters are `Int` and `Char`. While there are `Int` and `Char` instances for `Configurable` these are not picked due to the `Data b =>` constraints of `gunfold`.

Sorry if this post is a bit vague. I had a lot of trouble trying to explain this as clear as possible and english is not my first language.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    ScopedTypeVariables
  , DeriveDataTypeable
  , FlexibleInstances
  , UndecidableInstances
  , IncoherentInstances
#-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

class Configurable a where
  configure :: IO a

instance Configurable Int where
  configure = do putStrLn "Enter Int" ; read <$> getLine

instance Configurable Char where
  configure = do putStrLn "Enter Char" ; getChar

instance Data a => Configurable a where
  configure = do
    let dataType     = dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)
        constructors = zip (map show [1..]) (dataTypeConstrs dataType)
    putStrLn $ "Constructing " ++ show (dataTypeName dataType)
    mapM_ (\(i, c) -> putStrLn $ i ++ ") " ++ showConstr c) constructors
    ln <- getLine
    case lookup ln constructors of
      Just c  -> gunfold (<*> configure) return c
      Nothing -> do putStrLn "Unregonized answer" ; configure

data ABC = A Char Int | B ABC | C deriving (Show, Data)

main :: IO ()
main = (configure :: IO ABC) >>= print
```

Comment: You are confused about instance resolution. Instances are chosen at *compile time* -- the `(<*> configure)` call will never resolve at `Int`, because there needs to be *statically* an Int. The overlapping classes approach will not work.

Answer (score 3):

As @luqui points out in the comments, the instance selection process does not work in the way you assume.

Because of the signature of `gunfold` is has a higher-rank `forall`, the argument to `configure` is an existential type - and the compiler cannot do static instance selection on an existential.

Following this design requires a kind of dynamic dispatch. It's possible to build such a system out of language features (like using GADTs), but `Data.Data` basically already has what you want - just use `dataTypeRep` to check if the value you want to configure is a `Char` or `Int`. If you abandon the `Configurable` typeclass, one solution would be:

```hs
configure :: forall d. Data d => IO d
configure = do
  let dataType = dataTypeOf (undefined :: d)

  case dataTypeRep dataType of
    AlgRep constrs -> do
      let constructors = zip (map show [1..]) constrs
      putStrLn $ "Constructing " ++ show (dataTypeName dataType)
      mapM_ (\(i, c) -> putStrLn $ i ++ ") " ++ showConstr c) constructors
      ln <- getLine
      case lookup ln constructors of
        Just c  -> fromConstrM configure c
        Nothing -> do
          putStrLn "Unrecognized answer" 
          configure
    IntRep -> do
      putStrLn "Enter Int"
      ln <- getLine
      return (fromConstr (mkIntegralConstr dataType (read ln)))
    CharRep -> do
      putStrLn "Enter Char"
      ln <- getLine
      return (fromConstr (mkCharConstr dataType (read ln)))
    FloatRep -> do
      putStrLn "Enter Float"
      ln <- getLine
      return (fromConstr (mkRealConstr dataType (read ln)))
    NoRep -> do
      error "Type is unrepresentable!"
```

(I've also changed `gunfold` to `fromConstrM`, because `gunfold (<*> f) return = fromConstrM f`).

---

As a minor comment: a rule of thumb is that there is no good reason to turn on `IncoherentInstances` - it is much more likely that the type system simply cannot support the operation you want.

Comment: +1 on the "minor comment".  Never turn on `IncoherentInstances` without understanding **exactly** why you need to.  (Or better yet, never turn on `IncoherentInstances` period.)  The `UndecidableInstances` extension is different -- it's usually safe to turn that on whenever the compiler suggests it.